# Local instance setup instructions

Tags: openfda

I'd like step by step instructions for setting up OpenFDA in my lab.
The goal is to have the available pipelines populate and update the data in Elasticsearch so that I can make use of Kibana for research.
I have been unsuccessful in attempting this myself and would greatly appreciate any walkthrough, detailed setup instructions, or other advice.